Not receiving data from WebSocket proxy
I have 3 servers. On Server A (172.16.2.5), the following Python application creates a WebSocket connection to Server B (172.16.2.6) and repeatedly sends a message:
from time import sleep
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://172.16.2.6:80/")
while True:
    print("Sending...")
    ws.send("Hello world")
    print("Sent")
    sleep(5)

Server B is running websockify to handle the incoming WebSocket connection and forward the messages to an application running on Server C (172.16.2.7). Websockify is started on Server B using the following command:
./run -v 80 172.16.2.7:33333

Server C is running the following Python application to receive the messages from Server B:
import socket, time
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 33333))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print("Connected by", addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(11)
            print("Received: %s" % data)
            time.sleep(5)

When I start the application on Server A, it sends the messages with no errors:
Sending...
Sent
Sending...
Sent

On Server B, websockify prints out the following immediately after the application on Server A has started:
172.16.2.5: new handler Process
172.16.2.5 - - [07/Jun/2024 15:40:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 -
172.16.2.5 - - [07/Jun/2024 15:40:36] 172.16.2.5: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
172.16.2.5 - - [07/Jun/2024 15:40:36] connecting to: 172.16.2.7:33333

On Server C, the application prints out the following immediately after the application on Server A has started:
Connected by ('172.16.2.6', 32906)

There are 2 problems:

The application on Server C blocks on the call to conn.recv(11) forever until I stop the application on Server A. Once the application on Server A is stopped, the application on Server C finally starts printing out the Received:  messages every 5 seconds.

The application on Server C does not receive any data from Server B. It just keeps printing out Received: b'' every 5 seconds. I would expect it to print out Received: Hello world every 5 seconds.



in Server C you should exit while-loop when it gets empty data. It is standard method in many situations. if not data: break

recv() is blocking code so you don't need sleep()

some programs may need \n at the end to send or receive data.

you may use program telnet to test your socket. Start telnet 172.16.2.7 33333 and write some text and press ENTER.

I tested code for Server C using telnet and it seems it works. I tested code for Server A using websocket server created with other module websockets (with char s at the end) and it also works. But I don't know how to test websockify. I used client from module websockets and it raise error because websockify doesn't work with "text frames".

I found information how to test wesockify with netcat and wscat but I didn't test it - websocket - Websockify does not pass information further, connection is dropped prematurely - Super User

when I add websocket.enableTrace(True) in code for Server A then it also shows problem with "text frames". So it seems all problem can be wesockify

Thank you furas! Changing to the websockets module fixed the first problem. For the second problem, I found this discussion and fixed it by changing the code on Server A to ws.send("Hello world".encode()). Now Server C prints out Received: b'Hello world'.

You could describe it with details and with new code as answer below - and you may mark you answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote your answer.
